# How do i redirect back to homepage after mode_write seo friendly url in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am working on creating SEO friendly urls for CMS i have successfully achieved it but i am facing problem of redirecting .

index.php

```
<nav>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
</nav>

<a href="blog/24">Read</a>
```

After clicking on "Read" link in index.php its redirecting to blog.php as http://localhost/cms/blog/24
and by using php GET i can fetch id

blog.php

```
<nav>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
</nav>

<container>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
//i am getting id here
}
?>
</container>
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ blog.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ blog.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(css|img|js|images)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [L]
```

After clicking on read link i am redirecting to http://localhost/cms/blog/24 and i can get blog id of 24

but if click on home link in nav section of blog.php it is redirecting to http://localhost/cms/blog/index.php and it is giving object not found error

But i want it to be http://localhost/cms/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a slash to represents path relative to the document root

If your files are located in the root of the domain then change

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="/gallery.php">Gallery</a>
```

Else if in a subfolder on domain

```
<a href="/subfolder/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="/subfolder/gallery.php">Gallery</a>
```